# Java 8 Streams map versus peek

Tags: java, java-stream

Can someone explain to me why peek and map produce different outcomes in this code ?

````
List<String> alphabets = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"a","b","c"});         

List<String> upper1 = alphabets.stream().peek(l -> l.toUpperCase()).collect(Collectors.toList());        
upper1.forEach(System.out::println);         

List<String> upper2 = alphabets.stream().map(l -> l.toUpperCase()).collect(Collectors.toList());        
upper2.forEach(System.out::println);```

Output :-
a
b
c
A
B
C
````

Comment: peek doesn't  return any thing, It is for debugging

Comment: You can modify an existing object in a peek function. `String.toUpperCase` returns a new Object.

Comment: Peek does return something as the specification shows :- " Stream<T>  peek(Consumer<? super T> action)
Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream, additionally performing the provided action on each element as elements are consumed from the resulting stream."

Answer (score 4):

Peek is an intermediate operation and exists mainly to support debugging, where you want to see the elements as they flow past a certain point in a pipeline.

An example of how peek could be used in your code:

```
List<String> alphabets = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"a","b","c"});         

List<String> upper = alphabets.stream()
           .peek(l -> System.out.println("Filtered value: " + l))
           .map(l -> l.toUpperCase())
           .peek(l -> System.out.println("Mapped value: " + l))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
upper.forEach(System.out::println);
```

This outputs:

```
Filtered value: a
Mapped value: A
Filtered value: b
Mapped value: B
Filtered value: c
Mapped value: C
A
B
C
```

While the results of map is a stream of the results applying the given function in peak it's just the original stream of the results.
And since strings in java are immutable the result of peak won't be affected by executing the function.

If the elements were references (as objects) and the peek function updated the content of that references they would have been updated, but it's not the case here.

An example of peek with a MyString object:

```
class MyString {
    String str;

    MyString(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    public void toUpperCase() {
        str = str.toUpperCase();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        super.toString();
        return str;
    }
}

List<MyString> alphabets = Arrays.asList(new MyString[]{new MyString("a"), new MyString("b"), new MyString("c")});

List<MyString> upper = alphabets.stream()
        .peek(l -> l.toUpperCase())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

upper.forEach(System.out::println);
```

see the full code here:

http://tpcg.io/6GlwFizW

You can see there that the output is:

```
A
B
C
```

as we are altering the inner state of each element in this case.

Notice that I did on purpose that MyString.toUpperCase() returns void instead of a MyString object, so it would fail with map this way.

Comment: I already know that peek exists mainly to support debugging, this doesnt answer the question I asked.

Comment: Ok, my bad, I've added more info to the answer to try to answer the question this time.